# KeyError: 'return' on Shapelets platform

Tags: python, dataframe, function, radio-button, altair

I was trying to create a function on the Shapelets platform by combining the radio group and the Altair function. The goal is to be able to display the graph depending on the selection made. I segmented my choice in a dictionary and then referred to it in my function, however, when I am trying to run the code I have this error `KeyError: 'return'`.
Here is my code:

```
def print_selected_option_1(categories: dict, radio: str):
    melted_cat = pd.melt(categories[radio].reset_index(), id_vars=['postalCode'], var_name='Feature', value_name='Count')

    # Create stacked bar chart
    chart = alt.Chart(melted_cat).mark_bar().encode(
        x='postalCode:N',
        y='Count:Q',
        color='Feature:N',
        tooltip=['postalCode:N', 'Feature:N', 'Count:Q']
    ).properties(width=600, height=400, title=f'Bar Chart by Zipcode and {radio}').interactive()
    return app.altair_chart(chart=chart)

radiogroup = app.radio_group(list(categories.keys()))
app.place(radiogroup)

altair_chart = app.altair_chart()
altair_chart.bind(print_selected_option_1, categories, radiogroup)
app.place(altair_chart)

app.register()
```

Comment: Does your altair plot work outside of shapelets? If so it is probably an issue with shapelets and it might be better to open an issue on their github

Answer (score 0):

I see what is happening here, you forgot to define your function return.
here what you can do to fix it,

```
def print_selected_option_1(categories: dict, radio: str)-> Altair:
    melted_cat = pd.melt(categories[radio].reset_index(), id_vars=['postalCode'], var_name='Feature', value_name='Count')

    # Create stacked bar chart
    chart = alt.Chart(melted_cat).mark_bar().encode(
        x='postalCode:N',
        y='Count:Q',
        color='Feature:N',
        tooltip=['postalCode:N', 'Feature:N', 'Count:Q']
    ).properties(width=600, height=400, title=f'Bar Chart by Zipcode and {radio}').interactive()
    return app.altair_chart(chart=chart)
```

it should work right now, you can also look at our documentation where everything is fully explained https://new.shapelets.io/doc/user-guide/dataapps/widgets.html#server-side-functions